# Porque mi Grid se pega a la izquierda en responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive, grid

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola me pueden ayudar, en un media query meti un CSS GRID y todo se recarga a la izquierda adjunto foto, quisiera que todo se centrara, ya intente con align ítems

Este es mi CSS

@media (min-width:768px){
.barra1{

```
align-self: center;
padding: 0rem 4rem;
padding-bottom: 0;
padding-top: 7.5rem;

}

.barra1 .nav1{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 2fr);
    grid-column-gap: 5rem;
    grid-row-gap: 1rem;

}

.barra1 .nav1 a{
    font-family: var(--fuenteprincipal);
    font-size: 4rem;
    color: white;

}
```

}

este es mi CSS

Comment: Por favor añade tu código para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: es necesario el html para poder responder correctamente, pero a simple vista te diria que estas usando mal el align-self: center, deberias poner a .nav1 aling-items:center o align-self: center a los elementos "a". Pero sin el html no estoy segura del todo si ese es tu problema